# How to commit code to a subfolder on Github

Tags: git, github, directory, repository, commit

I create a repository Exercises on Github and have have subfolders in it as following:

```
Repo Exercises
       Part 1
       Part 2
```

In each subfolder, I will push separate project React app from my computer.

How can I do it ?

Comment: pull the repo, put your exercises in the folders, add, commit, push?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is missing some information:

1. Is the project on your computer git initiated?

If not, run `git init` in the terminal in your project folder.

2. Have you set up your GitHub repository as a remote origin?

If not, run `git remote add origin https://github.com/user/repo.git` in the terminal in your project folder.

Once these two steps are done, any changes in your project which are then **added**, **committed** and **pushed** from your computer to the GitHub repository should update the GitHub repository. This includes creation of new folders and files.